# "best in town" for something not in town

Tags: phrase-usage

I checked Google Word for "best in town" and it looks like this phrase is commonly used for food and eateries.

Both foods and eateries belong to a class of things that can be found only in some geographical location, hence the phrase 'in town'.

I wonder if this phrase can be applied to something that can't be pinpointed to a particular physical location.

For example, could I say something like:

> Check out those five websites. You won't regret it. They are best in
> town!

Comment: I wouldn't use it, but I would understand it.

Answer (score 2):

As a speaker of US English, I would not use "best in town" for anything that is not literally "in town".  It is not idiomatic for "the best that there is".

More idiomatic would be saying that they are ["(the) best in (their) class"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/best-in-class) or that they are ["the best around"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-best-around.420878/).

Comment: So, in your usage, "in town" means literally in town, right?

Comment: Yes, "in town" means literally in town.